# Package pgf Error: No shape named java is known - problems with points in the name

Tags: tikz-uml

I try to design a class diagram with `tikz-uml`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface ]{java.util.Collection}               
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface, y=-4, x=-3]{java.util.List}              
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface, y=-4, x=0]{java.util.Queue}              
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface, y=-4, x=3]{java.util.Set}

%           \umldep{java.util.List}{java.util.Collection}
%           \umldep{java.util.Queue}{java.util.Collection}
%           \umldep{java.util.Set}{java.util.Collection}
    \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

This one above works, but when I try to define a dependency like

```
\umldep{java.util.List}{java.util.Collection}
```

I get the following error:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named java is known. ...ldep{java.util.List}{java.util.Collection}
```

Probably the problem is the points in `java.util.List`, isn't it? But I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tikz-uml` package uses the label text of a node as internal node name. In TikZ/pgf some characters are not permitted or otherwise problematic in node names, such as `.` or `,` or `:`. Internally, `tikz-uml` therefore makes some substitutions when the node names are processed. You can add an additional substitution for `.` to be able to refer to those nodes in class dependencies.

Minimally, you need to edit `tikz-uml.sty` version 1.0 around line 457, where the general class node name substitutions are defined. Modify the code into something similar to

```
\StrSubstitute{\tikzumlClassNodeName}{:}{@COLON@}[\tikzumlClassNodeName]%
\StrSubstitute{\tikzumlClassNodeName}{.}{-}[\tikzumlClassNodeName]%
\StrSubstitute{\tikzumlClassNodeName}{\_}{@UNDERSCORE@}[\tikzumlClassNodeName]%
```

which replaces `.` with `-` when nodes are created only. For referring to those nodes you should use the replaced string.

MWE after this modification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface ]{java.util.Collection}               
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface, y=-4, x=-3]{java.util.List}              
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface, y=-4, x=0]{java.util.Queue}              
        \umlemptyclass[type=interface, y=-4, x=3]{java.util.Set}

           \umldep{java-util-List}{java-util-Collection}
           \umldep{java-util-Queue}{java-util-Collection}
           \umldep{java-util-Set}{java-util-Collection}
    \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

This approach can be improved by including the extra code from your own document with `etoolbox`/`xpatch` and by also patching the other node name macros to be able to use dots also in the `\umldep` command and similar. Alternatively (and cleaner) would be to rewrite `tikz-uml` a bit to accept an optional node name which can be different from the text label.